# How to get the values from "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array called `selectedArray`. This is an array of objects, here is a sample:

```
selectedArray
:Array[1]
0:Object
category_id:"8"
created_at:"2016-11-04 14:14:28"
lft:"17"
name:"Felt Materials"
rgt:"22"
updated_at:"-0001-11-30 0:00:00"
__proto__:Object
```

I have this code below. It is looping over `selectedArray`. The loop looks at the `lft` and `rgt` values of an identically constructed array called `nodesWithchildren`. When it finds an object that meets the condition I want it to pull that object out and create a new array called `childNodes`

```
 var childNodes=[];

  for(i=0; i < selectedArray.length; i++){
   if((selectedArray[i].lft /1 ) > (nodesWithchildren[0].lft /1) && (selectedArray[i].rgt/ 1) < (nodesWithchildren[0].rgt/1)) {
    childNodes += selectedArray[i];
        }
    }
```

Now it all works great except for one problem, `childNodes` comes out like this:
 `"[object Object][object Object]"`

I am new to Javascript and I have spent all day Googling for how I can get this into the same format as `selectedArray`. I have not even been successful in parsing these objects, as most of the examples I have found need to acccess the keys. However,  I **can** pull out individual values as strings if I do this: `childNodes += selectedArray[i].name`;

But for me that is not good enough, as my next chunk of code uses `filter` and that wants to see the two arrays in the identical format ie:

```
  var filtered=selectedArray.filter(function(e){return this.indexOf(e)<0;},childNodes);
```

Any advice? TKS !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`childNodes` is an array, but you are using string concatenation. You should be pushing the object onto the array instead

```
childNodes.push(selectedArray[i]);
```

Comment: `[Object object]` should be a tell-tale sign to you from now on that something isn't right! ...unless that really is what you are expecting.